# User-Assigned Managed Identity for Function App to access its own (hosting) storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I have created a User-Assigned Managed Identity that I have assigned to a Function App. I want to replace the Access Key connection string with the User-Assigned Managed Identity for the Function App to connects to its own stage, i.e., the hosting storage for the Function App. I have given the Storage Account Contributor, Storage Blob Data Owner, Storage Queue Data Contributor and Storage Table Data Contributor roles to the User-Assigned Managed Identity. What needs to be done to replace to storage account Access Key connection string with User-Assigned Managed Identity? I have tried to renaming the configuration AzureWebJobsStorage to AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName and replacing the Access Key connection string with the storge account name, as described in this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial, however this does not seem to work. I’m unable to reach the function app and get the following error in the logs: *"statusCode":400,"message":"Unable to load requested managed identity.*

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue and if 'yes' what was the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up at this question researching the same, so sharing what I've learned:

The default pattern for using __accountname, __credential en __clientId that works for other managed identity based connections works here as well. You can use this for using user-assigned managed identities.

Found the hint at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/use-managed-identity-instead-of-azurewebjobsstorage-to-connect-a/bc-p/3927119#M1478

Source and documentation for these properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob&pivots=programming-language-csharp#common-properties-for-identity-based-connections

Answer (score 0):

I found my way here as my function which has several identities, decided to use an assigned user managed identity to try and connect to its `AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName` rather than using the system (which it is using for blob/file share with no issues).

The settings to control this behaviour are documented below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-configure-durable-functions-with-credentials